# How can I disable profanity filtering of autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, keyboard, 4.2-jelly-bean, input-methods, gesture-typing

I'm using a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.2. I started using the baked in Swype imitation/gesture typing as soon as I found out it was there. However, the profanity filtering is extremely frustrating. It's way too liberal - it won't even recognize "sucks." I poked around a bit but can't find anywhere to disable it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type it in once, click it, and save it. Done.

You can also go to Settings > Language and Input > Personal Dictionary and add your words from there.

Comment: Doesn't work. Android already recognizes most of them as valid words.

Comment: OK, then type in some gibberish, click it, then again to save to dictionary. When the dialog comes up, replace it with whatever word you want and save. Just did this with 4.2.2 default keyboard and it works.